# On Screen Keyboard Pop Up Automatically

Tags: javascript, linux, raspberry-pi, electron, raspbian

I'm building an application with Electron running on a Raspberry Pi. I want an on screen keyboard to pop up automatically whenever a textbox is selected. How can I accomplish this? Either a Linux or a JavaScript solution would work.

Comment: http://xmodulo.com/onscreen-virtual-keyboard-linux.html –– That Florence keyboard app worked pretty well for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried something like:

```
<input type="text" onclick="require('child_process').exec('matchbox-keyboard');" />
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. Would you know if it can also hide itself? I want it to work similar to a mobile keyboard, where it can pop up/hide automatically on focus

Comment: Try to kill the process on `onblur` event